# Programmatically Disabling System-wide Touch Gestures in Win32 C++ Application on Windows 10

Tags: winapi, windows-10, touch

I'm creating an application that locks down some functionality in running apps on Windows 10 and I would like to selectively disable/enable certain system-wide touch gestures using the Win32 C++ API on a standard windows desktop application (not UWP). I've attempted the solution outlined at the following link with no results:

[Programmatically enable / disable multitouch finger input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066192/programmatically-enable-disable-multitouch-finger-input)

I attempted placing the recommended functionality in my window proc as well as executing the code before the message loop begins using the GlobalAddAtom(...) and neither approach worked. Reading the documentation didn't yield a reason why so I thought I'd ask the community. Does anybody know how to achieve this? Thank you community! :-)

Comment: Generally you can't/shouldn't make programmatic changes to system-wide settings, only for your own app.

Comment: `WM_TOUCH` and `WM_GESTURE` are orthogonal (see [Getting Started with Windows Touch Gestures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wintouch/getting-started-with-multi-touch-gestures): *"If you call `RegisterTouchWindow`, you will stop receiving `WM_GESTURE` messages."*). The referenced Q&A changes the behavior of `WM_TOUCH` message generation, but you seem to be interested in suppressing gestures. And if you are looking for a global solution, you'd have to apply whatever changes to **every** window. And even if you did, applications can handle input any way they like.